# urlconnection not uploading file to ftp server

Tags: java, android, ftp, android-edittext, urlconnection

hello all  i am developing an android app that has an functionality  of uploading files to ftp server i want my app to upload an Html file to ftp server i am using this code---
please answere. Thanx in advance...
here goes the code.. only the main code..

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {


                    String host = "www.ethicstrain.tk";
                    String user = "user";
                    String pass = "pass";
                    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"index.htm";
                    String uploadPath = "public_html/"+str+"/index.htm"; // str is input from editText.
                    String filename = "index.html";





                    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer( "ftp://" );


                       sb.append( user );
                       sb.append( ':' );
                       sb.append( pass);
                       sb.append( '@' );

                    sb.append( server );
                    sb.append( '/' );
                    sb.append( str );
                    sb.append( '/');
                    sb.append(filename);


                    sb.append( ";type=i" );

                    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
                    try
                    {
                       URL url = new URL( sb.toString() );
                       URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();

                       bos = new BufferedOutputStream( urlc.getOutputStream() );
                       bis = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(filePath ) );

                       int i;
                       // read byte by byte until end of stream
                       while ((i = bis.read()) != -1)
                       {
                          bos.write( i );
                       }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                       if (bis != null)
                          try
                          {
                             bis.close();
                          }
                          catch (IOException ioe)
                          {
                             ioe.printStackTrace();
                          }
                       if (bos != null)
                          try
                          {
                             bos.close();
                          }
                          catch (IOException ioe)
                          {
                             ioe.printStackTrace();
                          }
                    }
                 }




        }).start();
```

and the Logcat:

```
07-05 09:46:28.055: W/System.err(1123): java.io.IOException: Unable to connect to server: null
07-05 09:46:28.055: W/System.err(1123):     at libcore.net.url.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:203)
07-05 09:46:28.055: W/System.err(1123):     at libcore.net.url.FtpURLConnection.getOutputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:339)
07-05 09:46:28.065: W/System.err(1123):     at dolphin.developers.com.facebook1$DownloadFileFromURL$3.run(facebook1.java:382)
07-05 09:46:28.065: W/System.err(1123):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: is there an ftp server reachable under this address? maby firewall blocks it, or it runs under a different port?

Answer (score 0):

Whats up to this line:

```
sb.append( server );
```

Where does the server variable come from. If its not set than u will get an exception. I guess u copied it from an tutorial and forgot to change it. U should use ur host variable but without the 'www.'

Oh, just noticed the logcat sais:

```
07-05 09:46:28.065: W/System.err(1123):     at dolphin.developers.com.facebook1$DownloadFileFromURL$3.run(facebook1.java:382)
```

Do you try to access facebook, could it be that the error happening at some other place which you have not shown yet?

Comment: yeah i fixed that now but it give me same  errors  and thank you for anwereing

Comment: no i facebook is the name of my class that downloads facebook phishing page from my server and then upload it  to the folder which i mention in editText column.

Comment: download filefromurl is a Asynctask

Comment: sry I don't know where the error came from. i would guess it's appendent to the server connection. your application can't access the server or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line  `sb.append( server );` to `sb.append(host);`

Moreover, user and pass - are they the real username and password for the ftp server you are trying to access?

And, how are you using filePath and uploadPath? For you information, you didn't add them to the StringBuilder object.

Try your download using a hard coded url like this -

```
 URL url = new URL( "ftp://youruser:yourpass@www.ethicstrain.tk/yourfile");
 URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
```

Check this article for more help how it works - [click here](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/use-urlconnection-to-download-file-from-ftp-server)

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am trying this with a valid username and password and i have changed sb.append( server ); to sb.append(host);

Comment: Try hard coding you ftp url like below and check if you are successful.
URL url = new URL("ftp://<put your connection credentials here>);

Comment: i tried that but its not working.anyway thanx for answereing.

Comment: I guess one of the fields you are using is not reachable. I suggest you try to correcting your hard coded url.

Comment: i tried but its not working and giving the same error i used this URL url = new URL("myusername:password@www.ethicstrain.tk/"+str+";type=i");

Comment: What's str? Can you expand it and put the string?

Comment: str is the name of folder to which the file is uploaded